# Clicking My Logins then closing then re-opening this will cause a error

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, openid, login

If you open My Logins and then close it, and then open it again you will get an error. This happens in Chrome and Safari on OSX 10.7. I have not tested on anything else.

A picture of the error.

[image]

**UPDATE:**
It also happens when opening, then closing, then reopening a flag dialog box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're clicking too fast. I can trigger this as well, but if I wait two more seconds, then it loads normally. I guess that when you click the link the second time, the first popup has not been completely destroyed yet (you get the same message if you try to open the dialog when it is already open).

Comment: http://www.youreholdingitwrong.org/